# right mouse button not working

Tags: lubuntu, microsoft-mouse

I am using Lubuntu 14.04 for over a year and suddenly my right click button does not work and I am unable to right click anywhere

I tried the following commands:

```
sudo su
echo options pmouse proto=exps > etc/modprobe.d/pmouse.conf
```

Specifications:

- HCL Desktop
- Frontech motherboard
- 2GB Ram
- Microsoft Usb Mouse

Comment: @MarvinMicek: please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/588878/revisions).  Don't just review for caps lock, but check spelling, grammar and improve readability as well!  ;-)  Thank you!

Comment: Thnx. I didn't know how to write the codes in box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this sucks, but checking the obvious, did you verify that this is not hardware failure?  Does the mouse work on another system?

Comment: yup! it turned out to be a hardware problem. It was also not working in win xp. Thnx.

Comment: It's looks like I also have a hardware problem. Right button click works as left button click on both Linux and Windows. However somehow Chrome is able to figure this out and the mouse work properly there. Is there are any way to tweak it on the system level, so it works as expected in all the applications?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my mouse. It turned out that if the battery gets weak the right mouse button stops working. It's always good to look for a simple solution first.

Comment: Good one, if OPs mouse is wireless.

Comment: I disagree with above votes: Sometimes a low-tech solution is the best... :P  ;-)  **Voted to keep open.**